# Flip to pause feature for android music player

Tags: android, android-music-player

Can you help to implement flip to pause feature in Android music player? Looking for the positive reply.
For more ref: [Youtube video of flip to pause feature](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9KSLJYaRFQ)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can detect flipping like this:

Activity Code:

```
public class AndroidDetectFlipping extends Activity {

    SensorManager sensorManager;
    Sensor accelerometerSensor;
    boolean accelerometerPresent;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        List<Sensor> sensorList = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        if(sensorList.size() > 0){
            accelerometerPresent = true;
            accelerometerSensor = sensorList.get(0);
        }
        else{
            accelerometerPresent = false;
            face.setText("No accelerometer present!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        if(accelerometerPresent){
            sensorManager.registerListener(accelerometerListener, accelerometerSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        if(accelerometerPresent){
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(accelerometerListener);
        }
    }

    private SensorEventListener accelerometerListener = new SensorEventListener(){

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            float z_value = arg0.values[2];
            if (z_value >= 0){
                // Current condition is "FACE UP" \\
                // do your stuff according to this\\
            }
            else{
                // Current condition is "FACE DOWN" \\
                // do your stuff according to this\\
            }
        }};

}
```